# AWS Datapipeline, EmrActivity step to run a hive script fails immediately with 'No such file or directory'

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I've got a simple DataPipeline job which has only a single an EmrActivity with a single step attempting to execute a hive script from my s3 bucket.

The config for the EmrActivity looks like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Extract and Transform",
  "id" : "HiveActivity",
  "type" : "EmrActivity",
  "runsOn" : { "ref" : "EmrCluster" },
  "step" : ["command-runner.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/scripts/hive-script --run-hive-script --args -f s3://[bucket-name-removed]/s1-tracer-hql.q -d INPUT=s3://[bucket-name-removed] -d OUTPUT=s3://[bucket-name-removed]"],
  "runsOn" : { "ref": "EmrCluster" }
}
```

And the config for the corresponding EmrCluster resource it's running on:

```
{
  "id" : "EmrCluster",
  "type" : "EmrCluster",
  "name" : "Hive Cluster",
  "keyPair" : "[removed]",
  "masterInstanceType" : "m3.xlarge",
  "coreInstanceType" : "m3.xlarge",
  "coreInstanceCount" : "2",
  "coreInstanceBidPrice": "0.10",
  "releaseLabel": "emr-4.1.0",
  "applications": ["hive"],
  "enableDebugging" : "true",
  "terminateAfter": "45 Minutes"
}
```

The error message I'm getting is always the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/aws/emr/scripts/hive-script --run-hive-script --args -f s3://[bucket-name-removed]/s1-tracer-hql.q -d INPUT=s3://[bucket-name-removed] -d OUTPUT=s3://[bucket-name-removed]" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.CommandRunner.main(CommandRunner.java:13)
...
```

The main error msg being "... (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory".

I've logged into the master node and verified the existence of `/usr/share/aws/emr/scripts/hive-script`.  I've also tried specifying an s3-based location for the `hive-script`, among a few other places; always the same error result.

I can manually create a cluster directly in EMR that looks exactly like what I'm specifying in this DataPipeline, with a Step that uses the identical `"command-runner.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/scripts/hive-script ..."` command string, and it works without error.

Has anyone experienced this, and can advise me on what I'm missing and/or doing wrong?  I've been at this one for awhile now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm able to answer my own q, after some long research and try-error.

There were 3 things, maybe 4, wrong with my Step script:

- needed the 'script-runner.jar', rather than the 'command-runner.jar', as we're running a script (which I ended up just pulling from EMR's libs dir on s3)
- need to get the 'hive-script' from elsewhere - so, also went to the public EMR libs dir in s3 for this
- a fun one, yay thanks AWS; for the Steps args (everything after the 'hive-script' specification)...[need to comma-separate every value in it when in DataPipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html) (as opposed to space-separating as you do when specifying args in a Step directly in EMR)

And then the "maybe 4th":

- included the base folder in s3 and specific hive release we're working with for the hive-script (I added this as result of seeing something similar in [an AWS blog](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1PU7JM7I34L81/ETL-Processing-Using-AWS-Data-Pipeline-and-Amazon-Elastic-MapReduce), but haven't yet tested whether it makes a difference in my case, too drained with everything else)

So, in the end, my working EmrActivity ended looking like so:

```
{
  "name" : "Extract and Transform",
  "id" : "HiveActivity",
  "type" : "EmrActivity",
  "runsOn" : { "ref" : "EmrCluster" },
  "step" : ["s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script,--base-path,s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/,--hive-versions,latest,--run-hive-script,--args,-f,s3://[bucket-name-removed]/s1-tracer-hql.q,-d,INPUT=s3://[bucket-name-removed],-d,OUTPUT=s3://[bucket-name-removed],-d,LIBS=s3://[bucket-name-removed]"],
  "runsOn" : { "ref": "EmrCluster" }
}
```

Hope this helps save someone else from the same time-sink I invested.  Happy coding!